# Error with chronology and babel packages : "! Paragraph ended before \pgffor@next was complete."

Tags: babel, shorthands, pgffor, chronology

I am trying to use the chronology package in a report that includes babel. 
My distribution : `pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)`

On below my **MWE** :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage{chronology}
\begin{document}
\begin{chronology}[5]{1983}{2010}{10cm}[7cm]
\event{1984}{\color{blue}{one}}
\event[1985]{1986}{\small{two}}
\event{\decimaldate{25}{12}{2001}}{\huge{three}}
\end{chronology}
\vspace{5cm}

\begin{chronology}*[5]{1983}{2010}{10cm}
\event{1984}{\color{blue}{one}}
\event[1985]{1986}{\small{two}}
\event{\decimaldate{25}{12}{2001}}{\huge{three}}
\end{chronology}
\vspace{5cm}

\begin{chronology}[5]{1983}{2010}{10cm}[13cm]
\event{1984}{\color{blue}{one}}
\event[1985]{1986}{\small{two}}
\event{\decimaldate{25}{12}{2001}}{\huge{three}}
\end{chronology}
\end{document}
```

Actually, I get this error :

> ```
>  ! Paragraph ended before \pgffor@next was complete.
> ```

However, when I remove the line

```
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
```

The compilation is working fine. How can I fix it please ?

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` after loading package `chronology`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @Johannes_B : I receive the following error `! I can't find file tikzlibrarybabel.code.tex'.`

Comment: Maybe you need to do an update of your Tex distribution.

Comment: @Johannes_B my Tex distrubution : `pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)` I think it is the latest.

Comment: put `\litfiles` in the very first line of your document, and let it finish (no errors). Somewhere in the log is the version of tikz. `tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)` in my case

Comment: @Johannes_B [Reported and fixed](https://github.com/lwiseman/chronology/issues/4). Please feel free to contribute if necessary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug which has been fixed in version 1.1.1 of the package `chronology`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
[...]
\usepackage{chronology}
\let\CHRONOLOGY\chronology
\let\endCHRONOLOGY\endchronology
\def\chronology{\shorthandoff{;}\CHRONOLOGY}
\def\endchronology{\endCHRONOLOGY\shorthandon{;}}
[...]
```

The `;` is an active character in french, but used in TikZ. An environment like `chronology` is internally defined as `\chronology` and `\endchronology`. I save the old definitions, insert the active character handling and then use the old definition.

Comment: Will it cause an issue in the next lines of my report (ie if I use `;`)  ? What are the consequences of these two commands please ?

Comment: see my edited answer. In that case there should be no problems. The redefinition makes The `;` inactibe inside the `chronology` environment. Ouside it has the default behaviour.

Comment: It seems to solve the issue. Do you mind explaining a bit more what was the issue  and the commands please ? I wish I could understand what these 4 lines are doing.

Answer (score 6):

As @herbert already explained in his answer, `;` and other characters are active in french. This is conflicting with TikZ, which is using `;` to end a drawing command.

To resolve the issue, one can use the tikzlibrary `babel`, which isnt doing more than

```
\tikzset{
  handle active characters in code,
  handle active characters in nodes
}
```

Now, you can still use the shorthands in your nodes.

As there are other possible conflicts with active chararcters using build in functionality seems reasonable. You can find more information about whats going on in the [tikz-documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

Putting it all in a compilable example gives:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage{chronology}
%\tikzset{
%  handle active characters in code,
%  handle active characters in nodes
%}
%or
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{chronology}[5]{1983}{2010}{10cm}[7cm]
\event{1984}{\color{blue}{one?}}
\event[1985]{1986}{\small{two;}}
\event{\decimaldate{25}{12}{2001}}{\huge{three!}}
\end{chronology}
\end{document}
```